# Renaming positions in the template XML manifest file

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am converting theme from HTML to Joomla. When I have defined position in below manner, It gave me nothing as output.

```
    <positions>
        <position>top_header</position>
        <position>left</position>
        <position>right_menu</position>
        <position>right_content</position>
        <position>footer</position>
    </positions>
```

But When I changed that into following code, Everything is working fine.

```
    <positions>
        <position>position-0</position>
        <position>position-1</position>
        <position>position-2</position>
        <position>position-3</position>
        <position>position-4</position>
        <position>position-5</position>
        <position>position-7</position>
        <position>position-8</position>
        <position>position-9</position>
        <position>messageIE</position>  
        <position>debug</position>
    </positions>
```

As I am new to joomla, I don't have any idea why is it so.

So anyone can tell me why position works in that manner? Can't we define our own position in Joomla? Because I have seen themes which have their own defined position and they were working perfectly.Then Why my position did not work?

Comment: If you are changing the XML file once the template is already installed, go to your template manager, select your template, then click "save" without making any changes

Comment: My default positions was top_header, left etc. I uploaded my zip with this positions only.Then Would it work ?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a zip file for your template by any chance? I've honestly no idea why something which should be pretty straight forward isn't working. It could be down to various reasons.

Comment: Are you sure you are also setting the modules to appear in the new template positions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you based your new template on an existing template?

There are several conditions that must be met in order to display modules in your new positions.

1. **`/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/TemplateDetails.xml`**
   You must define your module positions in this file. Your code in the question is correct.
2. **`/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/index.php`**
   The positions must be defined in your `index.php` file. Place this code wherever you want your module positions to appear:

   ```
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top_header" style="xhtml" />
   ```

   (Replace "top_header" as needed)

[image: jdoc:include]

This code will be replaced with your module content **if** a module is published to this position.

3. **Publish your modules**
   Now publish a module (or several) to the position `top_header`, and make sure you set "Menu Assignment" -> "Module Assignment" to the pages where you want the modules to display. Also make sure "Status" is set to "Published".

[image: Module Assignment]

Most of these steps are basic, but I'm listing them because it's easy to overlook something.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file probably doesn't accept underscores _ in the module position name. Try using "top-header" instead of "top_header".

Comment: Do you have any source for this? I know it's not common to use `_` in module position names, but I just tested on Joomla 3.3, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @johanpw sadly, I can't find any sources online. But I remember having the same problem and fixing it by using a hyphen instead of underscore.